# What is equivalent for Windows API in Android?

Tags: java, android, api

I have a few experiences on Windows automation using Windows API and now I want to make some automations in Android apps.

At the moment, I am using ADB and it works great, but it needs my phone rooted.
Therefore, I want to deep dive into the lower API like Windows API.
I know there is Android API, but I can't find any materials to simulate events outside the source code of application.

What are some references related to it?

Comment: There is no API for it.  Android runs on Linux so you can do it at that level, but you'd need a rooted app writing directly to the /dev files to simulate input.  There is purposely no API to do this from another app for security reasons.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks for quick reply. It's sad to know. Since there is no public way to access /dev/ directory of current android version, I think I will stick with adb until there is another option.